# Can a painting make a sound or music?

Tags: visible-light, acoustics

In painting colors gives the image form,by the temprature of the color.Warm and cold colors makes the painting come alive.But can an image or painting of color  make a sound.Maybe not in the ear But in your head or have the same effect as a sound has on a human?

Since As fare as I know Sound comes from Light And all colors comes from White light.Matter/Mass cannot exist without the reverberation of sound.So can we see sound?So can we listen to a painting?

**Can a painting make a sound or music?**

(No expert,just thinking)

Comment: Sound does not come from light.

Comment: Are you thinking of  [synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia)?

Comment: There's no physical basis for your question, but you might be interested in the psychological phenomena: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia

Comment: @Asher Sound does not come from Light?Well Thank you anyway

Comment: -1 This is for sure not a physics question

Answer (score 1):

> Since As fare as I know Sound comes from Light And all colors comes from White light.Matter/Mass cannot exist without the reverberation of sound.

I'm sorry to tell you this, but i feel like I must. This statement has no basis in fact whatsoever. light and sound phenomena have nothing to do with each other. Light is an excitation of the electromagnetic field, while sound is vibrating matter. Light can travel through space in the absence of any matter, while sound is a wave that must have a matter medium to travel through, such as air, water, metal, etc. The two phenomena operate completely independently from one another. I've heard some odd pseudoscience before, but you found a real doozie!

There is however a psychological phenomena called synesthesia that can result in a person hearing sound when they see different colors, taste different foods, or feel different textures. It's a very interesting type of hallucination, but the subject is not receiving any real audio input.

Comment: What can I say.Im no expert

Comment: If someone can hear color.Can there be a mistake ,maybe they Are getting real audio input?

Comment: By what mechanism?

Comment: @Aigle there are two different concepts here. "Sound" is pressure variations in a material (e.g. air) which can be measured objectively in a lab. "Hearing" is a purely psychological phenomenon, which happens in your brain. There are many ways that people "hear things" which don't have any physical origin - and quite likely, for some people, "looking at paintings" may be one of those ways.